# React Child Component Update issue

Tags: reactjs

Following is my code

```
class Court extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clubs: [],
            clubId: 0
        };

        this.onClubChange = this.onClubChange.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.auth.user.type == 'admin'){
            this.props.fetchClubs().then(
                (res) => this.setState({
                    clubs: this.props.clubs
                })
            );
        }
        else {
            this.props.fetchClubs(this.props.auth.user.id).then(
                (res) => this.setState({
                    clubs: this.props.clubs
                })
            );
        }
    }

    onClubChange(e){
        this.setState({ clubId: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        const { clubs, clubId } = this.state;
        var clubsOptions = clubs.map(function(club){
            return (
                <option key={club.id} value={club.id}>{club.clubName}</option>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div className={classnames('form-group')}>
                        <label className="control-label">Clubs</label>
                        <select
                            name = "clubId"
                            onChange={this.onClubChange}
                            className='form-control'
                            value={ clubId }>
                            <option value="0">Select Club...</option>
                            { clubsOptions }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
                { this.state.clubId != 0 ? <Courts clubId={this.state.clubId} /> : null }
            </div>
        );

    }
}

Court.propTypes = {
    auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    clubs: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    fetchClubs: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        clubs: state.clubs.clubs,
        auth: state.auth
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchClubs })(Court);
```

When I change dropdown value, a state change occur but the data is not updated in child component Courts

```
{ this.state.clubId != 0 ? <Courts clubId={this.state.clubId} /> : null }
```

Secondly, first time option selection from dropdown is showing perfect data but after that no change shows up

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way;

```js
class Court extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clubs: [],
            clubId: 0
        };

        this.onClubChange = this.onClubChange.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.auth.user.type == 'admin'){
            this.props.fetchClubs().then(
                (res) => this.setState({
                    clubs: this.props.clubs
                })
            );
        }
        else {
            this.props.fetchClubs(this.props.auth.user.id).then(
                (res) => this.setState({
                    clubs: this.props.clubs
                })
            );
        }
    }

    onClubChange(e){
        this.setState({ clubId: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        const { clubs, clubId } = this.state;
        var clubsOptions = clubs.map(function(club){
            return (
                <option key={club.id} value={club.id}>{club.clubName}</option>
            );
        });
        
        let courts = <Courts clubId={this.state.clubId} />;
        let courtsView = this.state.clubId != 0 ? courts : null;

        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div className={classnames('form-group')}>
                        <label className="control-label">Clubs</label>
                        <select
                            name = "clubId"
                            onChange={this.onClubChange}
                            className='form-control'
                            value={ clubId }>
                            <option value="0">Select Club...</option>
                            { clubsOptions }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
                { courtsView }
            </div>
        );

    }
}

Court.propTypes = {
    auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    clubs: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    fetchClubs: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        clubs: state.clubs.clubs,
        auth: state.auth
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchClubs })(Court);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But its not still updating

Comment: I explain the whole scenario. May be then You will get the issue

Currently, I have 3 Options in dropdown
Select
FCB
MCF

When I select FCB its shows data related to FCB, then I select MCF no change happen, Then I select 'Select' so the component disappear and then select MCF and now data displayed accordingly

Hope you get the issue

Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: I am a novice programmer. What should I look for

Comment: There is an example of using select in react. It looks like select does not support multiple selections. You choose one and the dropdown closes.

Comment: I am selecting one at a time. I think I can't able to explain the issue properly

Comment: Is this correct? "clubs: this.props.clubs" (it is inside "fetchClubs"), shouldn't you be using something with "res"?

Comment: Yeah Its loading the data properly but on the selection of this the data, Child component is not loading properly

Comment: But have you seen that "clubsOptions" is, in fact, something that you've passed via prop (```this.props.fetchClubs(this.props.auth.user.id).then(
                (res) => this.setState({
                    clubs: this.props.clubs
                })
            );```)? Maybe your solution is misleading to yourself.

Comment: Did you put a console.log in onClubChange and verify that the value was correct. If the value is correct I would suggest that instead of checking for a value in the render you put it in Courts. if (!this.props.clubId) return null;

Comment: After a bit of working I figure out that Courts Component has a child component which is not updating. Now Can you people guide me on that